# Book recommendation for Vedas in Hindi

Tags: vedas, book-recommendation

From where I can read all Vedas

1. Rigveda
2. Samaveda
3. Yajurveda
4. Atharvaveda

I'll prefer `PDF` format rather than hard copy, as I  mostly read on my tablet. Please suggest good sources from where I can download or purchase them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I would like to suggest a good Hindi translation of [**Atharva Veda Sanhita**](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookAtharvavedaSanhitaPart1)  by ShriRam Sharma Acharya. ,Published by Yug Nirman Yojna. This book is with original sanskrit shlokas and can be downloaded via the link provided in PDF format.

---

As you requested here is the link   ,where this book is avaliable for **online purchase** [**AWGP**](https://www.awgpstore.com/gallery/search/init?str=Atharva%20veda)

---

Also here is the Hindi Translation of Rig -Veda Samhita (Hindi),Which you can read online as well as can purchase it also [**Rig-Veda**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v3)

---

Here is [**Sama Veda Samhita**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/samved/v1.1)  link from the same Publication -

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the book you have shared is a scanned copy. I am looking for proper PDF version, I can even purchase it.

Comment: Plese go through the link.The book mentioned in answer is avaliable for purchase on their official site.

Comment: @Swiftpushkar the 4b one is incomplete so can u tell me where can I  find the rest of the verses by the same author.?

Comment: Yes it's available. I will try to look for it and will updated the answer.